# OpenGL array of points animation

Tags: arrays, opengl, animation, 3d, 2d

I am trying to animate random point that i have created so they move across the screen and re-appear this is what i have done so far but does not work.the code is not the completed version of what i have i have only posted what i thought would be enough for this question could anyone help me animated the points

```
void TimerFunc(int value)
{
  xpos[0]=xpos[0]+0.25;
  glutPostRedisplay(); 
  glutTimerFunc(25, TimerFunc, 1);
}
struct Point
{
  float rship;
};
std::vector< Point > points;
void display(void)
{

glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   /* clear window */
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);        /* white drawing objects */
/* define object to be drawn as a square polygon */   

//Draw points
glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );  
glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Point), &points[0].x );   
glPointSize( 1 ); //1 pixel dot
glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, points.size() );
glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
//glEnable( GL_POINT_SMOOTH );/*round smooth points*/
glFlush();     /* execute drawing commands in buffer */


}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
for( int i = 0; i <250; ++i )
{
    Point pt;
    pt.x = -100 + (rand() % 200);
    pt.y = -100 + (rand() % 200);
    points.push_back(pt);
    xpos[i] = pt.x;
    ypos[i] = pt.y;

}
```

Comment: So..... what does your code do? What do you expect it to do? What is wrong with it. Please be more specific. Don't just expect us to compile your code, or read it and immediately notice that there is an error.

Comment: You need to post code that compiles or at least makes some sense. `Point` doesn't seem to have fields `x` and `y`. Why do you have both `points` and `xpos`? They seem to mean the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_? Do you get compile errors or segmentation faults? Do you see the points but they are not moving? Do you not see the points? Do you see them moving in a way you don't like?

Comment: @ Shabaz i see the points but they are not moving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick 'n dirty:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Point
{
    float x, y;
    unsigned char r, g, b, a;
};
std::vector< Point > points;

void timer( int value )
{
    // move all points left each frame
    for( size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i )
    {
        points[i].x -= 1;

        // wrap point around if it's moved off
        // the edge of our 100x100 area
        if( points[i].x < -50 )
        {
            points[i].x = 100 + points[i].x;
        }
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(30, timer, 1);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-50, 50, -50, 50, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // draw
    glColor3ub( 255, 255, 255 );
    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glEnableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
    glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Point), &points[0].x );
    glColorPointer( 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(Point), &points[0].r );
    glPointSize( 3.0 );
    glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, points.size() );
    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutCreateWindow("Scrolling Points");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutTimerFunc(30, timer, 1);

     // populate points
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i )
    {
        Point pt;
        pt.x = -50 + (rand() % 100);
        pt.y = -50 + (rand() % 100);
        pt.r = rand() % 255;
        pt.g = rand() % 255;
        pt.b = rand() % 255;
        pt.a = 255;
        points.push_back(pt);
    }    

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: u r amazing god bless u mate i know im asking for too much from you but please could u send me this code with a few coments so i can understand it better this is my email... u dont have to but i would be greatful this is my email ledikola@hotmail.com